# View like checkbox without the check?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, view, checkbox

I'm wondering if there is a view like the checkbox, but without the checkbox part? I just want a nice clean list of items with just the text portion showing, still allowing click events.

Comment: It's like asking for a fruit basket without the fruits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `ListView` in your main.xml file:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then create an `ArrayAdapter<String>`. Do the following for initializing an arrayadapter and listview:

```
ListView listView1 = new ListView();
String[] listOfItems = new String[] {"item1", "item2", "item3", "etc"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfItems);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

That's all you have to do to create a listview with a list of textviews. If you want to create a onclick() listener, then add the following code:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View clickItem, int itemPosition, long itemId)
    {
        // Add code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is just a regular TextView in a ListView with click handling: see http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html for an example.